# Django - How to serialize inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance, serialization, subclass

I walked through the documentation at https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html to learn more about the InheritanceManager.I won't add the `models.py` because it is the same as in the documentation.
So, here is my `views.py`:

```
class PlaceList(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Place.objects.select_subclasses()
```

As you can see, the line `return Place.objects.select_subclasses()` returns all the Bar, Restaurant or Place instance stored in the database.

My `serializers.py` looks like the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from genericRelations.models import Place, Restaurant, Bar

class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('id', 'location')

class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('id', 'location', 'restaurant_name')


class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('id', 'location', 'bar_name')
```

I do not know how to modify the `PlaceSerializer` so that it also serializes/deserializes the subclasses of Place.
E.g. something like 'if a Bar instance is encountered, then use the BarSerializer' and 'if a Restaurant instance is encountered, then use the RestaurantSerializer'.

Note: When the URL is `.../places/` then `PlaceList` is performed which results in this output:

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "location": "Köln"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "location": "Köln"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "location": "Köln"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 4, 
            "location": "Köln"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 5, 
            "location": "Köln"
        }
    ]
}
```

But what I want is something like the following (a mix between Restaurant and Bars):

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "location": "Köln"
            "bar_name": "BarName 1"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "location": "Köln"
            "restaurant_name": "RestaurantName 1"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "location": "Köln"
            "bar_name": "BarName 2"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 4, 
            "location": "Köln"
            "bar_name": "BarName 3"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 5, 
            "location": "Köln"
            "restaurant_name": "RestaurantName 2"

        }
    ]
}
```

How do I have to change my `serializers.py` file so that Django can use the right serializer for the right model ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a good way to do this, but there is a package https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-polymorphic/   that provides polymorphic serializers for Django Rest Framework.    DRF doesn't, AFAIK,  provide for polymorphism in ModelSerializers.

You could use a Serializer and implement all the methods to detect and return the correct fields based on the data, but that's non-trivial.